# Why doesn't it create a deadlock?

Tags: java, multithreading, locking, deadlock

Please refer to the code below

```
package com.test;

public class DeadLock {

    private void method1() {

        synchronized (Integer.class) {
            method2();
        }
    }

    private void method2() {
        synchronized (Integer.class) {
            System.out.println("hi there");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new DeadLock().method1();
    }
}
```

As per my understanding, the code in `method2` should not be executed in any case, since `method1` holds the lock on `Integer.class` and `method2` tries to access the lock on `Integer.class` again. But to my surprise, the code runs fine and it prints "hi there" to the console. Can someone clarify?

Comment: Re-entrant (recursive) mutex? In this case mutex can be acquired multimple times from the same thread but will (dead)lock from multiple threads

Comment: why do you think it should deadlock? Its straightforward isnt it?

Comment: you can't get locks if you have only one thread.

Comment: I think there will be no prob if u calling other method from some method then that other method will be execute till that calling method will be in wait state. there is not dead local at all.

Comment: Nice question. Please see @ http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/deadlock.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Locks are owned by threads. If your thread already owns a lock, Java assumes that you don't need to acquire it a second time and just continues.

You'll get a deadlock if you start a *second* thread in `method1()` while holding the lock and the second thread executes the method `method2()`.

If you prefer code, then `synchronized` works like this:

```
Lock lock = Integer.class.getLock();
boolean acquired = false;
try {
    if(lock.owner != Thread.currentThread()) {
        lock.acquire();
        acquired = true;
    }

    ...code inside of synchronized block...
} finally {
    if(acquired) lock.release();
}
```

Here is code to demonstrate the deadlock. Just set `runInThread` to `true`:

```
package com.test;

public class DeadLock {

    private void method1() {

        synchronized (Integer.class) {
            boolean runInThread = false;

            if( runInThread ) {
                Thread t = new Thread() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        method2();
                    }
                };
                t.start();
                try {
                    t.join(); // this never returns
                } catch( InterruptedException e ) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                method2();
            }
        }
    }

    private void method2() {
        System.out.println("trying to lock");
        synchronized (Integer.class) {
            System.out.println("hi there");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new DeadLock().method1();
    }
}
```

Comment: Well i doubt it. actually what i want to say is if method1() acquires lock on itself then all other thread will be in waiting state na?

Comment: its little bit heavy explanation for the fresher like me :D haha anyways +1 for correct ans.

Comment: Doesn't matter how many threads call method1(), there will be no deadlock.  In order to have a deadlock, the program must have at least two locks.  A deadlock occurs when each member of some set of threads is holding one lock, and blocked waiting to acquire a lock that is held by one of the other members.  In the simplest case, Thread-1 holds lock A and is blocked while trying to get lock B.  Lock B meanwhile is held by thread-2 which is blocked trying to get lock A.  Neither thread in that situation will ever be able to make any progress.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you have misunderstood the concept.
A method never acquires a lock, the instance on which the method is invoked serves as a lock in case of synchronized method and in case of synced block the thread acquires the lock on specified object.

Here the instance acquires the lock on Integer.class and then it goes on to execute method2.

There is no case of deadlock as in your case thread continues for the execution of the method that you're calling inside method1. So there is no deadlock that happens.

Comment: instance doesnt acquire the lock.Lock will be acquired by the thread executing it.right?

Comment: ahh..sorry for the unclear reply. Yes, the thread acquires the lock. Updated the answer. In your case the thread will acquire the lock on Integer class literal if you had written synchronized methods instead of synced blocks your thread (main in this case) would'he acquired the lock on the new Deadlock() instance on which your method1 was invoked.

Comment: I think what you are trying to say is that locking via Java's `synchronized` keyword is _recursive_.  That is to say, a single thread (e.g., the main thread in the example) can enter any number of nested `synchronized` blocks on the same object (e.g., the Integer.class object).

Answer (score 0):

your code is equivalent to:

```
synchronized (Integer.class) {
    synchronized (Integer.class) {
        System.out.println("hi there");
    }
}
```

if the thread acquired the lock and entered the first `synchronized` block it will have no problem accessing the 2nd

to produce a deadlock the call to method2 should be executed by a different thread.

Comment: You can't create a deadlock using only one lock object.  See my comment on Aaron Digulla's answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
 synchronized (Integer.class) {
            method2();
        }
```

when you calling this `method2();` then its not giving lock to any kind of mehtod its continues goes to the method that you are calling means this.

```
private void method2() {
        synchronized (Integer.class) {
            System.out.println("hi there");
        }
    }
```

and after completing its returning. so there is no case of dead lock. hope this explanation helps.

Answer (score 0):

As already said, one thread can access more than one synchronised blocks when no other thread already blocks it. In that situation the same thread can reenter synchronised block because it already holds it from method1.

To cause the deadlock you have to use two thread at least and two different locks. It have to access two locks in the reverse order. Check out that code:

```
private void method1() throws InterruptedException
{
    synchronized (Integer.class)
    {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " hi there method 1");
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        method2();
    }
}

private void method2() throws InterruptedException
{
    synchronized (Double.class)
    {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " hi there method 2");
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        method1();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
{
    new Thread()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                new DeadLock().method1();
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }.start();
    new DeadLock().method2();
}
```

Comment: i think that solution must be very short and sweet and easy to understand.

Comment: When you use threads with java the solution would never be like that. But I've got it, so next time will do my best.